# iPhone 4 takes a huge time(20 seconds) to Convert an image taken using camera into png. Is there any ways to reduce this time?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Image was taken using an UIImagePickerController.

*[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imageFilePath atomically:YES];*

The size of the image is 4 MB to 6 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Scale or Crop the image once you take the pic from the camera and save that particular pic in png format this obviously saves the time.

Answer (score 3):

20 second isn't normal, You are probably using the processor for something else at the same time, do you have any animationn/transition you are doing while the conversion is made?

It might also make this step smoother by using [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079) (GCD):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ ... });
```